# c++ merge two structs and instantiate in a flat way

Tags: c++

How can I merge two structs and instantiate the merged struct in a flat way?
The user of the merged struct would not know that it was created via inheriting from multiple base structs.

```
struct S1 {
  std::string name;
  std::string city;
};

struct S2 {
   int age;
   int grade;
};

struct MergedStruct: public S1, public S2 {};
```

**Instantiate in a flat way**

```
MergedStruct m {
  .name = "Josh",
  .city = "NYC",
  .age = 8,
  .grade = 4
};
```

**Instead of**

```
MergedStruct m {
  {
    .name = "Josh",
    .city = "NYC"
  },
  {
    .age = 8,
    .grade = 4
  }
};

//Identifying all the base structs in order to create an instance is tedious and not always possible
```

Comment: This is treading on [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) territory.  Are you trying to make C++ look like some other programming language?

Comment: No. Having to know all the base structs in order to create an instance is tedious and not always possible.

Comment: *Having to know all the base structs* -- Don't you need to know them to get the name of the member variable(s)?  Look at your examples you say you want to achieve, i.e. the "flat way" -- where did those names come from?  Second, what if there are member variables of `MergedStruct` that has the same name as one in the base class?  What would the syntax look like in that case?

Comment: Yes, we would need to know the base classes.  Meant to say that nesting all the base structs (and their bases, and so on) makes things tedious and not very nice to look at.

Comment: To you second point - `MergedStruct`'s member would override the base's member. But I agree that this wouldn't really work out correctly.